# SQL ORDER BY an AS variable

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I have an sql query sorta like this:

```
SELECT

.....
price

..... AS distance

ORDER BY case
  ...
```

my question is, how can i use the calculated distance as a sorting element?

Comment: What do you mean by calculated distance? Not sure if I understood it.

Comment: like i select prices right? then from gps and shop lat, long I calculate every items distance from the customer, then I want to sort the products by distance first then product price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear for me what "distance" is in the question's query and why you put case in oeder by.

In general, you can mention field within ORDER BY clause either by its alias or by its number within the select clause. You can put some logic into ORDER BY as well

```
  select A,
         B as MyB,
         C - Z, -- <- Field #3: (A - #1, B - #2, C - Z - #3, D + F + G - #4 etc)
         D + F + G
    from MyTable
order by MyB asc,       -- <- by alias
         3 desc,        -- <- by field's number
         D + F + G asc, -- <- by some logic, here it's just copy + paste
         case           -- <- by some logic designed for ORDER BY only
           when (A > B + C) then
             1
           when (A > B)  then
             2
           else    
             3
         end desc
```

Comment: distance is the distance of the product from the device, and i need case clauses cause i have some conditionals, kisses :)

Comment: one last question, if i want to segment my query in blocks...? any ideas like every 2km increments...

Comment: @kangoroo: Sorry, but what do you means by "segment query in blocks"? Could you, please, provide an example? Do you mean union/union all? If do, you can use all the order by options with exception of aliases: you can mention only field's aliases within 1st query (that's before the very first union/union all).

Comment: hmm, ok, eg.
like sort by price within every 2km distance segments,
does that make sense?

Comment: Something like this? Should I make an integer divsion of distance by 2000 to find out a corresponding segment number? In this case
order by cast(distance / 2000 as Decimal(20, 0)) asc, -- intervals 0 for 0..1999, 1 for 2000..3999 etc
         price asc

Answer (score 0):

either use the same definition for `distance` in the `order by` clause:

```
select 
...
price
<some logic here> as distance
...
order by <same logic here>
```

or refer to the derived column from an outer `select`:

```
select * from
(
select
...
price
... as distance
...
) x
order by x.distance
```